# How to know how much memory is used by a query in clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I am trying to test performance of clickhouse to get sense how much memory i need for a dedicated server.
Currently I'm using PostgreSQL in production and now I want to migrate to clickhouse, so I inserted some of production data into a clickhouse server locally and executing the most used queries on production on clickhouse.
But I do not know how much memory does clickhouse use to execute these queries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some research I found the answer hope it help others.
clickhouse has table called 'system.query_log' that is used for storing statistics of each executed query like duration or memory usage
[system.query_log](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/system-tables/query_log/)

also there is table 'system.processes' that has information about current queries
[system.processes](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/show/#show-processlist)

Comment: I also had this issue. I searched the net and couldn't find any proper solutions. But your solution was the right way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following query to inspect recent queries. It returns memory use, query duration, number of read rows, used functions, and more:

```sql
SELECT * FROM system.query_log
WHERE type != 'QueryStart' AND NOT has(databases, 'system')
ORDER BY event_time_microseconds DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: To add to this answer, I'd like to share this site, which has some queries regarding memory usage in general: https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-setup-and-maintenance/altinity-kb-who-ate-my-memory/. Altinity has some great articles about Clickhouse.